# Using mailto: to submit a form

Tags: html, forms

I want to use a form which uses mailto to send the values typed in it to my e-mail.
The thing is that when I type the values and click on submit, Windows Live Mail loads and then I have to send the data entered in the form from the Windows Live Mail.
Is there a way to send the data entered the minute the submit button is clicked without
an e-mail application loading up ?

this is the form

```
<form method="post" action="mailto:oldman@chasm.bridge">
<p>
 What is your name? 
<input type="text" name="MyName" size="30" maxlength="50">
</p>

<p>
What is your quest?
<input type="text" name="Quest" size="30" maxlength="100">
</p>

<p>
<input type="submit" value="Answer These Questions Three">
</p>
</form>
```

Answer (score 2):

`mailto:` is specifically meant to open the email application on the client. It does not *send* an email all by itself. That would also be a bad idea, since it requires your website visitors to be correctly set up to send email, which is not necessarily a given.

You'll have to submit the form to a server-side script, which can send the values in an email.
Don't make the client do it.

Comment: "Don't make the client do it." - You can't make the client do it (unless you hack into clients` computer). I agree that the best way is to process the form on the server.

Comment: I've tried to do it using a php script, however when I click the submit button, it just takes me to a page with the plain php script text on it.. any idea why?

Comment: @Ali Because your server isn't correctly set up to run PHP. Please search for similar problems (they have been discussed before) or open a new question specifically about that problem if you were unsuccessful finding a solution.

Answer (score 1):

The mailto is purely client-side, and will only result in your browser opening up a mail client.

TO programatically send an email, you'll have to use a server-side language

Answer (score 1):

This can be done easily using `php`, like so.

```
<?php
 $to = "recipient@example.com";
 $subject = "Hi!";
 $body = "Hi,\n\nHow are you?";
 if (mail($to, $subject, $body)) {
   echo("<p>Message successfully sent!</p>");
  } else {
   echo("<p>Message delivery failed...</p>");
  }
 ?>
```