# Use form to generate e-mail

Tags: html, forms, email

**My Question:** How do I use an html form within an e-mail to generate an e-mail which the client default e-mail program can use.

**Note** I realize you can't send an e-mail directly from html. That's not my goal. I want to create an e-mail to be used by the default e-mail client. This form is also within an e-mail.

I'm a beginner to html so this could be easy *(and I'm open to style tips)*. Here's my form. What I want is described *in the comments*. Is what I'm trying to do possible?

```
<form action="mailto:@@SELECTED_DESTINATION@@" method="post" enctype="text/plain">
  Select an issue type:<br />
  <select name="destination"> <!-- I want this to be the destination address of the e-mail -->
    <option value="bug@bug.com">Bug</option>
    <option value="enhancement@enhancement.com">Enhancement</option>
    <option value="feature@fature.com">New Feature</option>
  </select><br />
  Enter an e-mail for others to be informed:<br /> <!-- I want this to go into the cc of the e-mail -->
  <input type="text" /><br />
  Enter a summary of your issue:<br /> <!-- I want this to be the subject of the e-mail -->
  <input type="text" /><br />
  Enter a Description:<br />
  <textarea rows="6" cols="60"></textarea><br /> <!-- I want this to be the body of the e-mail -->
  <input type="submit" value="Send">
  <input type="reset" value="Reset">
</form>
```

When I submit the report now, I get an e-mail with the `to` as `@@SELECTED_DEATINATION@@`, no `cc` or `subject`, and a `body` that looks like this:

```
Destination=bug@bug.com 
cc=cc-email@cc.com 
subject=subject of the e-mail 
body=this is a description
```

This is how I expected it to come out, but I would like to know how to make it come out with the `to` as the value of whatever destination option they selected, `cc` addresses as whatever they enter in the `cc` text field, the `subject` as whatever they enter in the `subject` text field, and the `body` as whatever they enter in the `body` text area. Thanks for the help!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Using mailto: to submit a form](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9970114/using-mailto-to-submit-a-form)

Comment: @Diodeus, not a duplicate. I know there's no way to submit an e-mail directly from HTML alone, and that's not my goal. Please *read* the **Note** at the top of the question before assuming it's a duplicate :) If that was you who voted to close the question, please remove your vote :) Thanks.

Comment: Email does not support the embedding of forms.

Comment: @Diodeus, for one, yes it does (I've done it myself and for an example of one of the many services which does this take a look at [Google forms](http://support.google.com/docs/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=87809)), and secondly if that were true your comment could be an answer (if it were true).

Comment: http://www.campaignmonitor.com/resources/will-it-work/forms/

Comment: @Diodeus, I actually did decide to not use a form after all, so if you use that link (actually really useful) and write a couple lines of explanation in an answer I'll accept it so future comers will see my solution. Thanks for the link and sorry if I sounded a little irritated. You could have said that it's not a good idea, not that it's not supported. That would have been more accurate :)

Comment: Well I'd say it's supported, but not quite ready for prime-time. MS Outlook is the new IE6, in terms of backward (and I really mean backward in this case) compatibility. No worries. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This cannot be done due to limitations in e-mail clients (see comments to question). So the solution I thought of is having a link as follows:

```
<a href="mailto:destination@example.com?cc=Enter%20Other%20Watchers%20Here&subject=Enter%20Bug%20Summary%20Here&body=Enter%20Bug%20Description%20Here">destination@example.com</a>
```

This will load the user's e-mail client with a compose e-mail which looks like this:

- **To:** destination@example.com
- **Cc:** Enter Other Watchers Here
- **Subject:** Enter Bug Summary Here
- **Body:** Enter Bug Description Here